# CSS positioning - How to put one input next to another

Tags: html, css

I want to put the input "Favored CPF" on the right side of "Favored". How can I do this?

Here is an example: [image]

```html
<table border="0" style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="favorecido">Favorecido:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="favorecido" id="favorecido" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="favorecido_cpf">Favorecido CPF:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="favorecido_cpf" id="favorecido_cpf" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido_cpf'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using HTML tables to style your page?

Comment: You have forced them align within table structure!

Comment: Right. How do I solve this?

Comment: Do not use a table.... or put them in the same row....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform this simply using the table structure you have used you can just put them in the same `<tr></tr/`,

```
<table border="0" style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="favorecido">Favorecido:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="favorecido" id="favorecido" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
    <td><label for="favorecido_cpf">Favorecido CPF:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="favorecido_cpf" id="favorecido_cpf" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido_cpf'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As an aside, you may want to look into using [css-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to sort out your alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Make little sense to use a table for a layout. You would be better off changing the structure of the code. If you are really stuck with it, you can alter the display of the rows so they no longer act like rows.

```css
tr { display: inline-block }
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1-1</td>
    <td>1-2</td>
  </tr>     
  <tr>
    <td>2-1</td>
    <td>2-2</td>
  </tr>     
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either take the two inputs out of the table or put the two inputs in the same row of the table.

```
<!-- First Solution -->
      <div style="display:flex;">

        <input type="text" name="favorecido" id="favorecido" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" />
        <input type="text" name="favorecido_cpf" id="favorecido_cpf" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido_cpf'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" />


        </div>

        <!-- Second Solution -->

        <table border="0" style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

         <tr>
           <td><label for="favorecido">Favorecido:</label></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="favorecido" id="favorecido" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>

           <td><label for="favorecido_cpf">Favorecido CPF:</label></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="favorecido_cpf" id="favorecido_cpf" value="<?=$queryFornecedor->fields['favorecido_cpf'];?>" size="50" maxlength="100" /></td>

         </tr>
     </table>
```